# Get only first letter of all list items

Tags: 2013, list

I hava a SP custom list, I want to get only first letter of all list items but the proble is that I get only the first letter of first item.

my code:

```
function onS() {
    var lstString = "";
    var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (Enum.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
        lstString += currentItem.get_item("Title") + "<br/>";

    }
    $("#divCustomer").html(lstString.substring(0,1));//here I am using substring to get only the first letter and it works but it return only the first letter of first item (I have 10 items in custom list).
}
```

Comment: You are doing the substring **after** your while loop over all items. So you concatenate all Titles and then get the first letter of that (very long) string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to this:

```
function onS() {
    var lstString = "";
    var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (Enum.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
        lstString += currentItem.get_item("Title").substring(0,1) + "<br/>";

    }
    $("#divCustomer").html(lstString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var letters = [];//it is an array
    var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (Enum.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
        var letter = currentItem.get_item("Title").substring(0,1);
        letters.push( letter );//push one letter on the array
    }
    var lettersHTML = letters.join('<br/>');//create String with HTML between all letters
    $("#divCustomer").html( lettersHTML );
```

This separates your HTML from the processing and makes for better maintainable code.